# type erasure validation on runtime

Tags: java

I have read many answers and articles about type erasure and I understand that the type is excluded at runtime :

> Type erasure can be explained as the process of enforcing type constraints only at compile time and discarding the element type information at runtime.

so assume I have this generic class  :

```
public class Stack<E> {
    private E[] stackContent;

    public Stack(int capacity) {
        this.stackContent = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
    }
}
```

it will be compiled to :

```
public class Stack {
    private Object[] stackContent;

    public Stack(int capacity) {
        this.stackContent = (Object[]) new Object[capacity];
    }

    public void push(Object data) {
        // ..
    }

    public Object pop() {
        // ..
    }
}
```

I still don't understand if I create stack of "String" how it can ensure I won't insert Integer ?

```
Stack<String> stack=new Stack<String>(..);
```

if the type is removed and `push` function accept any object , how did it know I can insert only string ?

Comment: The type constraint is applied at compile type.

Comment: Because at compile time, it won't let you add other things than `String`s.

Comment: @daniu but doesn't it compile it to Object ? so anything of Object is applicable. when does it look for String ? is that part of erasure ?

Comment: It _obviously_ converts the types to objects ___after___ it made sure there is nothing in your code which adds things of a different type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fine question, seeing the "naive" answers. You are probably aluding the compiler compiling `A.java` with `B.class` containing type erased code.

At compile time `Stack<String>.push(Integer)` is erroneous. In the same java source this is no wonder.

However when the declaration is in another class, and only the compiled `.class` is given?

The dirty secret is that a [`<FormalTypeParameter>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.3) (already) is stored in the `.class` too. So slowly Java is moving to a time without type erasure. Also note that there are added runtime casts for type erased constructs. *These would raise a runtime error, when using non-generically the class: `Stack st = ...`.*

Answer (score 1):

You can't really know at runtime that only `String` will be inserted. The point here is to avoid bad things at compile time.

If you declare your push method with the following signature:

```
public void push(E element) { ... }
```

The Java compiler will throw an error if you try to call `push(12)` on a `Stack<String>`.

Erasure happen after the compilation. Type check is done using the real type.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trick. **You can't**.

When you declare `Stack<String> stack`, then at **compile time** JVM checks what you add `String` or `not String` and throws exceptions.

But at **runtime**, you can add anything what you want, like old JVM version (it was done to keep old code compileable at new JVM versions).

I.e. when you declare `Stack<?> stack` this is exactly what you have at runtime.

Comment: JVM? That's runtime, not compile time. You mean javac.

Answer (score 0):

The `Stack` itself compiles to `Object`, but the client classes will still have it as a stack of `String`s. ie

```
Stack<String> stringStack = new Stack<String>();
stringStack.push(-1);
```

is invalid *at compile time*. If you were to remove that information in the client, by using raw types, you'd do

```
Stack stack = new Stack(); // compile warning: raw type. client has removed information.
stack.push(-1); // will compile now
```